# How to handleRequest from html form in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have simple html form and controller to handle it. **Notice** I'm not using Symfony's forms in html.twig like `{{form_start(form)}} ...`. So I want to handle from simple html forms in Controller.

My request body is contains below

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#10
#parameters: array:2 [
    "name" => "name"
    "amount" => "name"
  ]
```

}

and in Controller.php I have $form

```
$defaultData = ['message' => 'Type your message here'];


    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('name')
        ->add('amount')
        ->getForm();

    //here I can't handle the request;
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    // only 'message' is contain
    dd($form->getData());
```

[How to Use a Form without a Data Class](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/without_class.html) From documentation I tried to handle request from html form without using `$data = $request->request->get('data')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all my tried to handle and asking in every Symfony forums, I founded this problem,

My mistake was just specify my requests parameters.
First I need to find out what is the name of my `$form` To solve this I dumped my $form that just created

```
dd($form);

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

After that my request should look like below
[image]

And after that I can handleRequest()!

Comment: You should add just after the `handleRequest()` an condition like this : `if($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted())` and retrieve your data when you're enter condition. And create a FormType class insteed create it on your controller :).

Comment: @Hamham thank you for your feedback, But I know how to work with form type, As I said how to retrieve data from simple html form, not symfony's form, so this is my answer.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood. Also, add object Request in argument of your controller and get them by `$request->request->getAll()` or `$request->query->getAll()` in function you use POST or GET form.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  There is a way to remove the 'form' portion of your element names so it works with 'regular forms'.  Takes a bit of explaining so I'd have to post an answer if you want to see it.  You could also search for a method with the somewhat unlikely name of getBlockPrefix.  You basically make your own form type class and add public function getBlockPrefix() { return '';} and the need for the form prefix will go away.